# Is it possible to differentiate between two objects that have the same variable in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, class, oop, attributes

I'll start by sharing the code.

```
import random

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius        

def radius():
    return random.randint(1, 10)

ball = Ball(radius())

ball = Ball(radius())

class Bag:
    def __init__(self, slots):
        self.slots = slots

bag = Bag([1, 2])

bag.slots[0] = ball

bag.slots[1] = ball

print(bag.slots[0].radius)

print(bag.slots[1].radius)
```

Both of the ball objects look exactly the same. The difference comes from the radius, due to it being randomly generated by my def radius() function. I want to be able to put the first ball into the first slot of my bag object, and the second ball into the second slot. As of now this is currently written, this is impossible. This is due to both ball objects having the exact same variable "ball". I can easily fix this problem by changing the names of the balls to something such as ball_1 and ball_2. *However*, I would like to keep the variable names the same. Is there a way to have Python understand which ball is which without changing the names, or will I just have to deal with them having different names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you want to go with this, but you dont need the ball variable:

```
import random

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius        

def radius():
    return random.randint(1, 10)

class Bag:
    def __init__(self, slots):
        self.slots = slots

bag = Bag([1, 2])

bag.slots[0] =  Ball(radius())

bag.slots[1] = Ball(radius())

print(bag.slots[0].radius)

print(bag.slots[1].radius)
```

Comment: This knowledge helps me so much. Thank you!